# Google-Colaboratory throwing "TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable" in code without errors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, typeerror, google-colaboratory

for some reason Google colab keeps on throwing errors everytime in code that has no errors,
an example is

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
scalar = tf.constant(7)
scalar
```

It throws an error for this which is **TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable**

I tried re-running it several times but that did not fix it, despite the code being correct. When I restarted and re-ran the code it worked but the code i had in my last line which was

```
matrix1 = tf.constant([[10, 7],
                      [7, 10]])
matrix1
```

does not work despite having the code

```
matrix = tf.constant([[10, 7],
                      [7, 10]])
matrix
```

which did work several lines above from this one.

- I tried again to restart it and re-run the code but it still did not work.
- I tried to update my google chrome because but my google chrome is at the latest version.
- I made a new notebook and tried the code and it works! but I need to use the notebook I have because I have already written a lot of code there.
- I also tried to update my operating system and now it is up to date. macOS Monterey 12.4 but it still did not fix anything.

The problem also occurs when i try to change a numpy array to a tensor

```
import numpy as np
numpy_A = np.arange(1, 25, dtype = np.int32) #create a Numpy arrary between 1 and 25
A = tf.constant(numpy_A, shape = (2, 3, 4))
```

and it is always **TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable**
that keeps getting thrown as the error.

and the code above is correct, I am following an online tutorial, and it worked and I kept checking my code over and over again but it is the same exact thing that was written. I am using the most up to date version of tensorflow as well which is **2.8.2**

I have looked up various ways to fix this but there is nothing I have found.

I am using colab.research.google.com for this code. And I have to keep using colab for the online course, in order to take notes, and run several things individually and follow along with the instructor.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @AloneTogether ```import tensorflow as tf ```
```print(tf.__version__)```
```scalar = tf.constant(7) ```
```matrix1 = tf.constant([[10, 7], [7, 10]]) ``` is an example

Comment: @AloneTogether I believe the problem is with google-colaboratory itself, because the code is correct, but google-colab keeps throwing the type error.

Comment: This is not reproducible with google colab.

Comment: I am able to run the mentioned code successfully without any error. Please check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/59a750ad494dfeb28a0dc7cb4b272715/-73054935.ipynb) for the same. You can try by clearing some cache from your browser and try running the code again. Please share the full standalone code which you are executing if the issue still persists.